# percentage character in output after compiling

Tags: c, unix, compilation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s", "Hello");

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello%
```

Why a `%` ? And why it disepear when i put a "\n" after "Hello" ?

Comment: That's probably just your shell's prompt. It should always appear. If you put a `"\n"` at the end of the `printf`, it will just be pushed to the new line

Comment: I cannot reproduce you error when testing on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: AFAIR some shells use that extra character to indicate the the `\n` was missing in the output.